# Epsilon Delta continuity proof

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, epsilon-delta

This should be a basic epsilon delta practice but I don't know how to prove it.
Define $H: X\times[0,1]\to Y$ by
$
     f(x) = \begin{cases} 
          F(x,2t) & t\in[0,\dfrac1 2] \\
          G(x,2t-1) & t\in[\dfrac1 2, 1] \\
       \end{cases}
    $

where F and G are continuous functions from $X\times[0,1]$ to $Y$ and $F(x,1)=G(x,0)$. I want to show that $H$ is continuous. It suffices to show that H is continuous at $t=\dfrac1 2$ since it is already continuous in $X\times[0,1]\setminus\{\frac1 2\}$. I wanted to state that F and G both converges to the same function at $t=\frac 1 2$ but it is not enough because it has to be continuous at every path around $(x,\frac1 2)$, I assume.

Comment: Are X and Y metric spaces.  How are the metrics defined.  In particular how is the metric on $X\times [0,1]$ defined compared to the metric on $X$.  Can we assume that if $d((x,t),(w,t)) < \delta$ that there is a $\delta'$ so that $d_2(x,w) < \delta'$?

Comment: This looks a lot like a setting where arbitray topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ are considered. In that case, there is no metric and hence no $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-criterion for continuity. Can you elaborate on whether $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces or not?

Comment: Ouch, you are right. They are just topological spaces, so I cannot prove by delta epsilon....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just roll up your sleeves and do it.

Consider the point $(w,\frac 12)$ and let $\epsilon  > 0$.  As $F,G$ are continuous there are $\delta_F, \delta_G$ so that if $D((x,y) - (w,\frac 12)||< \delta_{F,G}$ then $||F(x,2y)-F(w,1)|| < \epsilon$ and $||G(x,2y-1)-G(w,0)|| < \epsilon$.  Let $\delta = \min(\delta_F, \delta_G)$.

Now consider a point $(u,v)$ so that $||(u,v)-(w,\frac 12)|| < \delta$.  If $v < \frac 12$ then $||F(u,2v)-F(w,1)||=|f(u)-f(w)| < \epsilon$.  If $v> \frac 12$ then $||G(u,2v-1)-G(w,0)||=|f(u)-f(w)| < \epsilon$.  If $v = \frac 12$ then $F(x,2v)=G(x,2v-1)$ and $||F(u,2v)-F(w,1)||=||G(u,2v-1)-G(w,0)||=|f(u)-f(w)|< \epsilon$.

And we are done.

Comment: Ouch, I'm sorry. I just realized that X and Y are topological spaces, not necessarily a metric space. I was trying to figure out in metric spaces, so thank you for your answer anyway!